# AngularJs directive for only num does not work on IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, internet-explorer-11

I am using an angularjs directive that should ensure that an input field only accepts numbers.
The directive works on Chrome and FF, but it does not work on IE11

What does need to be added to make it work? or directives don't work in IE11? I am not sure, but if anyone would be able to help me out figuring out a work around, or if I am making a mistake in the code, that would be nice.

I am on version 11.0.9600.19596 - Update Versions: 11.0.170. In this version, I can type alphabetical characters inside the box, contrary to how it behaves in Chrome and FF.

I also tried it on IE11 Version 11.1392.17763.0 Update Version 11.0.205

Not sure what else to check.

Thank you,

Erasmo

AngularJS for onlynum

```
app.directive('onlyNum', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var keyCode = [8, 9, 37, 39, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 110];
            element.bind("keydown", function (event) {
                console.log($.inArray(event.which, keyCode));
                if ($.inArray(event.which, keyCode) == -1) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.onlyNum);
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                }

            });
        };
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="w-25 p-3">
    <label for="meeting-id">Meeting ID</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="meetingId" id="meeting-id" ng-trim="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Meeting ID" only-num />
</div>
```

Comment: i tried you code and i don't see any issues in IE11. my IE version is 11.1667.17134

Comment: @sandeepjoshi - I am on version 11.0.9600.19596 - Update Versions: 11.0.170. In this version, I can type alphabetical characters inside the box, contrary to how it behaves in Chrome and FF. Thank you

Comment: @sandeepjoshi - I also tried it on IE11 Version 11.1392.17763.0 Update Version 11.0.205

Comment: @Yu Zhou - I apologize for not getting back to you promptly, I was derailed to another task, I plan to test your code and as soon as I am done doing that, I will get back to you. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use below code sample and it can work well in IE 11 and other browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="w-25 p-3">
        <label for="meeting-id">Meeting ID</label>
        <input type="number" ng-model="meetingId" id="meeting-id" ng-trim="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Meeting ID" only-num />
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('test', []);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.name = 'World';
        });

        app.directive('onlyNum', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                    elm.on('keydown', function (event) {
                        if (event.shiftKey) { event.preventDefault(); return false; }
                        if ([8, 13, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(event.which) > -1) {
                            // backspace, enter, escape, arrows
                            return true;
                        } else if (event.which >= 49 && event.which <= 57) {
                            // numbers
                            return true;
                        } else if (event.which >= 96 && event.which <= 105) {
                            // numpad number
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```